# GMTK - "The Design of Dead Space" (Sountrack): genre?

Tags: identify-this-genre

In this [video](https://youtu.be/edcBLDNR2Ig) by GMTK, there is a really atmospheric soundtrack in the backdrop, which i can crudely guess to fall in the ambient category, but these sort of soundtracks are very commonly used in nature documentaries and the similar, where the listener has to be both made calm and intensified at the same time(thats what i feel). I would really want to know the particular genre this soundtrack falls into, and would also like to replicate the same melody, so if someone could provide the rhythm or chord pattern for the above, i would be really obliged!

Also, the music in the video is the most clearly heard at 0:40~0:50 and 12:40~12:50 in the video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that the most fitting genre to your example would be Ambient Soundscapes.

Within that genre there are then specific moods of soundscapes like relaxing, myterious, dark etc.

Comment: Actually that question you tagged was my question only. I asked the same question in the other site, Music:practice and theory. As no one was answering here. Although you did now, Thanks for that!!.

Comment: can this sort of music be called, 'rock' ambient?